# json_encode returning as undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

So I've been reading up on a few guides on using json to return values to JS from php. I've however encountered a bit of a problem. Right now, I've got a jquery-function (don't get distracted with 'id: 1', it's used for something else), such as:

```
$('#some_trigger').on('change', function(){
    $.post("retrieve.data.php", {
            id: 1
      }, function (data) {
          var values = data;

          alert(values[name]);
    });
});
```

And on the receiving end (in 'retrieve.data.php'), I've got:

```
$arr_assoc_template = array(
"name" => "aName",
"id" => "anId"
);

echo json_encode($arr_assoc_template, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

However, the console and alert window keeps logging [name] as undefined. What am I missing? :(

Comment: try `alert(values.name)` instead

Comment: set proper content type header also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse`, turns a string of JSON text into a Javascript object.

```
var values = $.parseJSON(data);

console.log(values.name);
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing double quotes around the `name` in `values["name"]` Or you can use `values.name`. The first option is better practice.

Comment: values["name"]  is bettter , rather than converting the json to string. Best of luck

Comment: can be single quotes also...type of quote not relevant here. Also saying *"is better practice"* is very subjective and is not the more common approach

Comment: types of qoutes are irrelavant but converting the json to string is extra overhead.